# Does this scratch (on the roof of a black car) look as though it was caused by a cat, please?

Tags: car, scratch

A neighbour has accused one of our cats of making a deep scratch in the roof of their car, and intends to bill us for the damage.
Apparently he has a number of 'quotes' ranging from £140.00 plus VAT to £400.00 plus VAT (we live in the UK) but has not revealed from where he has received these quotes.
To be fair, our cats sit on many car roofs, including our own cars (as do other people's cats in the area, and there are quite a few) but nobody else has noticed damage.
The only 'proof' he has is that he has seen our cat on the roof of his car; no photo / video of the cat on the car  - and we have it in written messages (from both him and his wife, separately) that at the time our cat supposedly did this damage these neighbours were away on holiday in their other car.
In any case, the scratch does not look like a cat-scratch as it is very wide and deep in places, is a strange shape, and clearly caused by just one claw  ... I would have thought a cat scratch would be a series of parallel claw-scratches.
I know it's difficult to 'tell' from a photo but I'm wondering if the attached photo (taken by the neighbour) could be considered a cat-scratch. Even a reputable national bodywork-repair company believes (after viewing the photo) that this scratch was not made by a cat.
I would be extremely grateful for any opinions please, from either side of the fence![image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I'm not a feline *expert*, I do love them dearly. I can tell you, the scratch shown in the picture was not made by a cat. Cats make straight scratches, not crooked ones like in the picture. A cat would have to make three directional changes in order to have made that. It was made with some kind of metal. It seems to me your neighbor needs to get a life ... but that is JMHO. Unless they have video of your cats making the scratch, tell them to pound sand.

Comment: Given that other cats also sit on vehicles, how in the world do they expect to prove it was *your* cat that could have *possibly* caused that damage?  (And, anyways, I agree with Paulster2 that it does not look like a typical cat scratch.)  With a reputable witness present, ask you cat if he/she did it, and if they don't confess, case closed! :)

Comment: This reminds me a bit of a situation where someone accused me of damaging their vehicle by backing up one of my cattle trailers into it.  They were adamant that I pay for repairs to the their vehicle, and even wanted their entire vehicle professionally repainted.  What they didn't know is that I had security cameras on my trailer, and they clearly showed their vehicle hitting my parked trailer.  The incredible thing was that, even after I showed them the videos, they continued to insist that somehow I was responsible for the damage to their vehicle.  Some people...

Comment: Keratin can't scratch glass. End of discussion.

Comment: I don't think I could make that scratch with my fingernails, no matter how much I sharpened them. I'm not sure how a cat with no leverage could have managed to carve that deeply!